# Python Ctypes NULL pointer access

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am integrating with a C library and in one of the method, I can get all of the data successfully except for a buffer pointer.

Here is the method definition

```
BOOL NET_DVR_ManualSnap(
  LONG                      lUserID,
  LPNET_DVR_MANUALSNAP      lpInter,  // input parameter
  LPNET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT    lpOuter   // output parameter
);
```

Here is the `NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT` struct definition

```
struct{
  DWORD                    dwSize;
  BYTE                     byResultType;
  ...
  BYTE                     *pBuffer1;
  BYTE                     *pBuffer2;
} NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT, *LPNET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT;
```

In my python side, both pBuffer1 and pBuffer2 are images made of pointer of bytes.

```
class NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("dwSize", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("byResultType", ctypes.c_byte),
        ("pBuffer1", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)),
        ("pBuffer2", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte))
    ]
```

When calling the method,

```
lUserID = 0
lib.NET_DVR_ManualSnap.restype = ctypes.c_bool

lpInter = NET_DVR_MANUALSNAP()
lpInter.byLaneNo = 1

lpOuter = NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT()

success = lib.NET_DVR_ManualSnap(lUserID, ctypes.byref(lpInter), ctypes.byref(lpOuter))

if success:
    print(lpOuter.pBuffer1.contents) // NULL pointer access
    print(lpOuter.pBuffer2.contents) // NULL pointer access
```

Comment: So lpOuter.pBuffer1 contains a null value. (It doesn't point to a null value; the pointer itself is a null value). Are you supposed to pass a buffer into the function, perhaps?

Comment: **What did you do with the seven bits left?**  Just use *bytes* not another types(int,string,bool,long etc.) I read the codes you wrote, but I couldn't see a description of the memory allocation. You cannot access definitions within C codes (values that cannot be saved), you can only call functions. STURCT is not a function!

Comment: @dsgdfg In this case the function name and struct definition is having the identical name. In my code I am indeed calling `NET_DVR_ManualSnap`, not the struct!

Comment: @immibis I assume we need to define the struct variable with some amount of size first?

Comment: **null** is undefined for python, try : return byte for true 0xFE and false 0xFF , **bool** can't be shared outer side! EOF not equal to null.

Comment: @dsgdfg I think you've misunderstood my question. Apparently I have no problem calling the function. My question is how can I access the variable `pBuffer1` from the output parameter `lpOuter`.

Comment: You didn't define function's *argtypes*. So you get 2 *NULL* pointers. Is this a problem? Maybe this is what you should have gotten (no license plate has been identified). What about the structure's members? You didn't do any initialization on the structure before passing it to the function. You should at least do `lpOuter.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT)`.

Comment: @CristiFati your comment got memmory allocation ! (+1) . And warning again **Just use bytes not other types**(LSB,MSB,EMPTY VALUES,ERRORS,ANSWER LENGTH, EOBP(end of bytes pointer),RAM SIZE EXCEED,BUFFER CLEAR METHOD,POINTER CLEAR METHOD) . Moore Tech You have to attend the C teaching.have nice day!